# Node js input values in text file

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, user-input, readline, file-management

I want to know how can I compare values received from user input with values stored into file.txt in Node.js.

update : I **do not** need to **store passwords in plain text**. The text file is used only for validation of the admin credentials. This meaning that The credentials are changeable through the text file and the admin has to know the credentials in order to log in. It may not make sense but it is for learning purposes.

Comment: It sounds like you're planning on storing passwords in plain text.  You should be storing salted hashes of passwords, not plain text.

Comment: No I do not need to store passwords in plain text. The text file is used only for validation of the admin credentials. This meaning that The credentials are changeable through the text file and the admin has to know the credentials in order to log in. It may not make sense but it is for learning purposes.

Comment: It sure looks like your example text file contains the email `admin@admin.com` and the password `admin`.  And the answer from Nguyễn Việt Đức that you said was "Awesome" reads the password out of the file in plain text.    You're right that so far it does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your learning purpose, simply compare strings. If your `userInputPassword` is in plain text and password stored in `admin.txt` is hashed, then you have to decrypt your password in `admin.txt` before comparing.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
 input: process.stdin,
 output: process.stdout
});
const read = fs.readFileSync('admin.txt', 'utf8');
console.log(read);
readline.question(`What's your email? `, (email) => {
 const userInputEmail = email.trim();
 console.log(`Email: ${email}`)
   readline.question(`What's your password? `, (password) => {
     const userInputPassword = password.trim();
     console.log(`Password: ${password}`);
     const [correctEmail, correctPassword] = read.split('\n').map(s => s.trim());
     if (userInputEmail === correctEmail && userInputPassword === correctPassword) console.log('Logged in');
     else console.log('Email or password is incorrect');
     readline.close();
   });
});
```

Comment: Awesome. It was a little confusing for me but it looks great now. So how can I do that if the credentials are correct my cli app continues with some other process like showing a menu options for the admin ? For example let it be 4 options to choose from. Shall I do it with inquirer or anything else. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: For command line applications, I recommend using a library like [commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js) rather than trying to create it yourself because you will have to nest many callbacks together.